# What does rf in rm -rf stand for?

Tags: unix, terminal

What does `rf` in `rm -rf` in Unix stand for?

More generally, I have a hard time remembering Unix commands and options because I don't understand what they stand for. Is there a resource that explain the meaning of these shorthands?

Comment: rm --help should give you a list of parameters and their meanings. Also check the man pages.

Comment: What is it exactly that this has to do with programming?

Comment: `man rm` will tell you. If you're using the GNU version, so will `rm --help` and `info rm` (or `info coreutils rm`).

Comment: This belongs to Unix/Linux forum.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In `rm`,

- `-r` stands for *recursive*
- `-f` stands for *force*

Doc :

```
man rm
```

said :

> ```
>     -f, --force
>            ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
>
>
>     -r, -R, --recursive
>            remove directories and their contents recursively
> ```

Answer (score 25):

`rm` means remove

`r` means recursive, which you have to use when removing an entire folder
`f` means force removal

combined, `rm -rf someDirectory` means **force the recursive removal of someDirectory**

Answer (score 5):

-r

> Recursively removes directories and  subdirectories
>                 in the argument list. The directory will be emptied
>                 of files and removed. The user is normally prompted
>                 for  removal of any write-protected files which the
>                 directory contains. The write-protected  files  are
>                 removed  without  prompting,  however,  if  the  -f
>                 option is used, or if the standard input is  not  a
>                 terminal and the -i option is not used.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is recursive force